# Completly bright camera image with python/opencv (even for no light)

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use opencv to obtain images via an USB-camera (DMK 23UP1300). Unfortunately the images are nearly completely bright, the intensity values are all between 250 and 255, even if there is no light (tested for python2.7 and 3.7). Does anybody know what the problem could be? I also updated the drivers for the camera, no effect. I even set down the exposure time to the minimal possible value, what had no impact. Please see the attached code as a minimal example:

```
import cv2


class Camera:
    def __init__(self):
        self.initialize_value = 0

    def GetImage(self):
        if self.initialize_value == 0:
            self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            self.cap.set(3,1280)
            self.cap.set(4,1024) 
            self.cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE,-13) # change exposure
            self.initialize_value = 1

        ret, im_orig = self.cap.read()
        #cv2.imshow("Livestream_Window",im_orig)
        self.im_main = cv2.cvtColor(im_orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        print(self.im_main)
        cv2.imshow("Livestream_Window",self.im_main)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        cam=Camera() #initialize camera

        ct=0
        while 1:
            print(ct)
            ct=ct+1
            cam.GetImage()  #Options: Camera, Image, Video
```

Comment: Does the camera show anything sensible in another capture software (such as VirtualDub if you're on Windows)?

Comment: @akx it works totally fine for ICCapture